# Rhythmbox can't find music on my Android device

Tags: arch-linux, mount, mp3, music, rhythmbox

Rhythmbox on my Arch Linux shows my smartphone on the devices list, but it's unable to find any music on it. I installed `mtp` and `mtpfs` and also enabled the mtp plugin in Rhythmbox. I also added a `.is_audio_player` file with this content:

```
audio_folders=Music/
folder_depth=2
output_formats=audio/mpeg
```

But no luck, the device is actually mounted fine and I'm able to browse through the files (using `gphoto2`) but if I try to play the files directly through the device they won't play either. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs)** or **jmtpfs** utility

```
sudo apt install go-mtpfs jmptfs mtp-tools
```

Plug in your smartphone and run this in terminal:

```
go-mtpfs ~/path-to-your-mount-point-folder
```

or:

```
jmtpfs ~/path-to-your-mount-point-folder
```

It will mount your device in userspace via fuse. So you can access your smartphone's filesystem as local fylesystem at `~/path-to-your-mount-point-folder` mount point.
There you'll find your music.

I found that **go-mtpfs** works faster.